# Replace image source in JSON String response

Tags: java, android, html, json, string

I need to to check if the JSON response I'm getting does contain an image source tag in it and replace or add a prefix in it then use Glide to download that image.

Actually, I'm unable to display images containing in the response due to the fact the image sources are internal and don't have domain name prefix in them.

For example:

```
<img alt=\"Image1\" src=\"/sites/default/files/Image1.jpg\"/>
```

This image won't get displayed.

Tried different ways to do this without success.

```
String htmlText = this.jsonContent.replace("src=\\", "src=\\https://somesite.com/");
```

What a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
     String jsonContent = "" +
            "<img alt=\"Image1\" src=\"/sites/default/files/Image1.jpg\"/>" + "\n" +
            "<img alt=\"Image1\" src=\"/sites/default/files/Image1.jpg\"/>" + "\n" +
            "<img alt=\"Image1\" src=\"/sites/default/files/Image1.jpg\"/>" + "\n" +
            "<img alt=\"Image1\" src=\"/sites/default/files/Image1.jpg\"/>";

    String htmlText = jsonContent.replaceAll("src=\"", "src=\"https://somesite.com");
```

Comment: there is no such key "image_source" in the jsonContent object. It is just a normal html body content.

Comment: then a html body is not json as you mentioned in the question. Are you getting html stubs in a json response?

Comment: I'm getting a string which contains html tags then I put the string in webview. But can't get images to display because the source is internal

Comment: Didn't need to use Glide here. Thank for your help